# Getting error "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used" when using if else loop

Tags: r, stringr

I'm an R newbie, trying to create a new column that takes time data from an existing column (12 hr format) and simplifies it. For example, change "12:45" to just "12", "4:00" to just 4, etc.

Here's what I have:

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(NewTimeColumn = if (str_detect(OldTimeColumn, "^12") == TRUE)  {
"12"
} else if (str_detect(OldTimeColumn, "^1") == TRUE) {
"1"
} else if (str_detect(OldTimeColumn, "^2") == TRUE) {
"2"
} else if (str_detect(OldTimeColumn, "^3") == TRUE) {
"3" 

## and so on

} else {
"11"
})
```

Here's the error messages I get:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (str_detect(tilt, "^12") == TRUE) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (str_detect(tilt, "^1") == TRUE) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

All values in the new column end up being "1"

Comment: Friendly reminder: try to make your question reproducible, by providing a data.frame using `dput()` and what you expect the output to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll most likely use `lubridate` to properly handle your `Time` column. Here is a mock-up example.

```r
#Data
df <- data.frame(Time = c("12:45", "6:00", "7:00", "8:11"))
# df
#   Time
# 1 12:45
# 2  6:00
# 3  7:00
# 4  8:11
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
library(lubridate)

#Convert Time column to proper time format 
df$Time <- hm(df$Time)
# now df looks like 
# df
#   Time
# 1 12H 45M 0S
# 2   6H 0M 0S
# 3   7H 0M 0S
# 4  8H 11M 0S
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Then create a column called Hour extracting the hour from Time
df$Hour <- hour(df$Time)
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# df
#         Time Hour
# 1 12H 45M 0S   12
# 2   6H 0M 0S    6
# 3   7H 0M 0S    7
# 4  8H 11M 0S    8
```

Hope that helps and saves a lop of nested `ifelse` beside properly handling time with a package designed to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

`if` and `else` should be used on logical conditions that are length 1. You are asking if a vector (`OldTimeColumn`) of some length `n` is equal to a vector of a single value `TRUE` -- so that's why the warning message says what it says, and it only evaluates the first element of `OldTimeColumn` by comparing it to `TRUE`.

A better way for your particular example might be to use the [`case_when`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) structure.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame(
  OldTimeColumn = c("12", "1", "2", "3", "4"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(NewTimeColumn = case_when(
    str_detect(OldTimeColumn, "^12") ~ "12",
    str_detect(OldTimeColumn, "^1") ~ "1",
    str_detect(OldTimeColumn, "^2") ~ "2",
    str_detect(OldTimeColumn, "^3") ~ "3",
    TRUE ~ "11"
  ))

df

  OldTimeColumn NewTimeColumn
1            12            12
2             1             1
3             2             2
4             3             3
5             4            11
```

Trying to do this with `ifelse` (which does work on evaluating vectors) would be more cumbersome but can be done:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(NewTimeColumn = ifelse(str_detect(OldTimeColumn, "^12") == TRUE,
         "12", ifelse(str_detect(OldTimeColumn, "^1") == TRUE, 
         "1", ifelse(str_detect(OldTimeColumn, "^2") == TRUE,
         "2", ifelse(str_detect(OldTimeColumn, "^3") == TRUE, "3", "11")))))
```